# How to create simple SPI slave protocol driver

Tags: android, adb, linux-device-driver, spi, device-tree

I have an Intrinsyc Open-Q µ820 eval board and a fully accessible header with SPI pins. On those pins, I want to connect a SPI slave. I have my linux kernel all set up with my dts file looking like this:

```dts
&soc {
    [...]
    spi_0: spi@7575000 { /* BLSP1 QUP1 */
        compatible = "qcom,spi-qup-v2";
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;
        reg-names = "spi_physical", "spi_bam_physical";
        reg = <0x07575000 0x600>, <0x07544000 0x2b000>;
        interrupt-names = "spi_irq", "spi_bam_irq";
        [...]    

        device@0 {  // Slave driver and CS ID
            compatible = "me,myDevice"; /
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <1>;
            reg = <0>;
            spi-max-frequency = <5000000>;
        };
    [...]
};
```

With my device, I want to write a driver to send custom messages with custom functions. It's been like a month I am working on this but I am not able to quite catch how I should do it.

The actual driver I wrote contains:

```cpp
static const struct of_device_id mySpi_id[] = {
    { .compatible = "me,myDevice", },
    { .compatible = "qcom,spi-msm-codec-slave", },
    {},
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, mySpi_id);

static const struct spi_device_id mySpi_dev[] = {
    {"myDevice", 0 },
    {},
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(spi, mySpi_dev);

static struct spi_driver myDevice_driver = 
{
    .driver = {
        .name   =   DEVICE_NAME,
        .owner  =   THIS_MODULE,
    },
    .probe      = myDevice_probe,
    .remove     = myDevice_remove,
    .id_table   = mySpi_dev,
};

static struct spi_board_info spi_board_info = {
    .modalias   = DEVICE_NAME,
    .max_speed_hz   = 5000000,
    .chip_select    = 0,
    .mode       = SPI_MODE_0,   // CPOL = 0, CPHA = 0
};
static int __init myDevice_init(void){[...]} // Don't know what to put here

static void __exit myDevice_exit(void){[...]} // Don't know what to put here
module_init(myDevice_init);
module_exit(myDevice_exit);

MODULE_ALIAS("spi:myDevice");
MOLULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

These structures seem to link my driver to my device. But I am not able to write the `.probe .open .write .read __init __exit` to configure my pins and write on them (like the SPIdev driver).

If I understand well for the DTS file, `qcom,spi-msm-codec-slave` is the SPI master under which I have to define my slave devices (e.g. ***device@0***). I have parsed all the spi driver in my linux repo and haven't been able to write something functionnal.

So my question is: How shoul I write my ***file_operations*** functions to act like SPIdev when using commands like 
`$ adb shell cat myDevice` and `$ adb shell echo "whatever" > myDevice`?

Comment: Before thinking of file operations, which you don’t need to implement — it’s not mandatory, check simple SPI slave driver, there are a lot examples under NFC, IIO and other frameworks.

Comment: The board info part is redundant since you gave device tree description.